# Formula to ignore or treat as empty a cell that contains another formula with no result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm using Excel 2007

I have a Cell B14 which contains a formula getting data from a different worksheet and sometimes this formula may have no result.

I need a formula to ignore Cell B14 or treat it as empty if this happens or return the result of the formula in B14 if there is one.

This is the formula I am using at the moment:

```
=IF(B14<>"","Not Empty","Empty")
```

But it sees the formula in B14 and treats it as the cell is not empty?

Comment: It would help if you updated your answer to include the formula that is in Cell `B14` so we can see what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No need to do anything different to IGNORE or treat the Formula Cell Empty if the Formula cell has NO RESULTS. Since Excel automatically IGNORES or treats it an EMPTY Cell.**

Let me showy how !!

[image]

1. **Blue Cells** are `A2` & `A3` has no value so that Formula in Cell `A5` returns ZERO.
2. **White Cells** are `B2` & `B3` has value `20` and `10`, Cell `B5` has formula adds cell `A5, B2 & B3` returns `30`.
3. This simple exercise shows that Excel automatically considers the Cell `A5` as Zero or no value cell.

**Note:** *Apply this Cell Format `0;0;"";"text"@` to display the Cell empty, if has ZERO.*

**Now the last part how to determine that the Cell has Formula but result is ZERO.**

```
=IF(AND(ISFORMULA(A5),A5=0),"Empty","Not Empty")
```

*Will return EMPTY.*

Comment: Glad to help you @kenny ,,,  keep aking !